# 504 Gateway timeout cause 70007 on Apache 2.4 + mod_proxy Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, mod-proxy

I am tired of so many tries to fix 504 Gateway timeout from mod_proxy in Apache 2.4 using PHP-FPM.
So i try to find a solution here. Actual i plan to migrate a Software from an old Apache Server to a new Ubuntu 18.04., 20 GB MySQL over 30 Million entries 98 tables, nothing big but sometimes slow.

The script is running but the long operations like User, Data deleting or Database optimization(5000s) ends withe a 504. Apache error log shows

```
[Fri Sep 20 22:08:44.426924 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9308] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 87.xx.204.109:62982] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https://test.xxxx
[Fri Sep 20 22:14:05.539446 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9308] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 87xx.204.109:62982] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https://test.xxxx
[Fri Sep 20 22:39:54.892255 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9273] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 87.x.204.109:50931] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https://test.xxxx
```

The first was to set `max_execution_time` to unlimted but without effect.
Second was `memory limit` and `input time` also without effect

I decided to set `request_terminate_timeout = 0` in PHP-FPM Pool also no effective [i know that is standard]. 
Maybe i have to setup a proxy_timeout but liveconfig, my Server-Management-System, administrate the vhost. I found solutions for Ngix but not for apache. I also tried mod_php, that works for the solution so i think the problem ist mod_proxy, the php-side is ok.

What can i do to raise up the timeout for mod_proxy over 5000s

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml|ps)$">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm/web0.sock|fcgi://localhost"
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
```

Can someone help me?
I found that i can use a timeout in

Answer (score 1):

By default, Apache uses the `Timeout` directive that is configured to `60` seconds.

To modify the timeout of proxied requests, you have to use `ProxyTimeout`.

For example:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyTimeout 180
</IfModule>
```

More information in Apache documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout

Comment: If you want to change the timeout for single domain, then add the above configuration inside <Virtualhost> directive. But if you want to increase proxy timeout for overall web server then add that inside Apache configuration file at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a solution after carefully reading the examples of https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html

Especially the example "Proxy via Handler" was helpful.

This should set the timeout for mod_proxy to '''OVER 9000!!!'''

```
    <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
       <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml|ps)$">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm/web0.sock|fcgi://localhost"
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
        </FilesMatch>
        <Proxy "fcgi://localhost">
            ProxySet timeout=9001
        </Proxy>
    </IfModule>
```

From the link above:

> "The part that is matched to the SetHandler is the part that follows the pipe."

The part `fcgi://localhost` has to be in `SetHandler` and `Proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed by link https://shouts.dev/articles/apache-proxy-fcgi-the-timeout-specified-has-expired-on-rhel
it is error timeout of apache